# Como salvar o resultado desse código numa lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

Fiz o seguinte código em python:

```
def exibir_menu():

    print('''Escolha uma opção:

    1. Cadastrar um aluno
    2. Listar alunos matriculados
    3. Procurar um aluno
    ''')


def cadastrar(pessoas):

    nome = input('Nome: ')     
    email = input('Email: ')
    curso = (input('Curso: '))
    pessoas.append((nome, email, curso))


def listar(pessoas):

    for pessoa in pessoas:
        nome, email, curso = pessoa
        print(f'Nome: {nome}, email: {email}, curso: {curso}')

def buscar(pessoas):

    pessoa_desejada = input('Nome: ')
    for pessoa in pessoas:
        nome, email, curso = pessoa
        if nome == pessoa_desejada:
            print(f'Nome: {nome}, email: {email}, curso: {curso}')
            break
    else:
        print(f'Pessoa com nome {pessoa_desejada} não encontrada')

def main():
    pessoas = []

    while True:
        exibir_menu()
        opcao = int(input('Opção? '))
        if opcao == 1:
            cadastrar(pessoas)
        elif opcao == 2:
            listar(pessoas)
        elif opcao == 3:
            buscar(pessoas)
        else:
            print('Opção inválida')


main()
```

Agora gostaria de salvar o cadastro (nome, email, curso) em um arquivo .txt, como eu faço?

Comment: Você sabe manipular arquivos com Python, abrir para leitura ou escrita, escrever no arquivo, etc? Ou é essa a sua dúvida?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar as seguintes funções:

```
def salvar(filename, info):
    file = open('{}.txt'.format(filename),'a', encoding='UTF-8')
    file.write(info+'\n')
    file.close()
    
def ler(filename):
    file = open('{}.txt'.format(filename),'r', encoding='UTF-8')
    return file.read()
```

Neste caso, você só teria que passar o nome do arquivo desejado em 'filename' e a informação formatada em 'info' para salvar.

Utilizo o '\n' para adicionar uma linha, para que cada vez que salvar, seja salvo e crie uma linha abaixo para o futuro registro.

Na função salvar() utilizo a leitura com 'a' (append) para poder adicionar informação, ao invés de sobrescrever (se fosse apenas 'w' [write]).
Para saber sobre leitura de arquivo, pode fazer uma leitura rápida [neste link no W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp)

#### MAS!

Eu particularmente recomendaria você salvar em arquivo .csv, uma vez que o mesmo pode ser utilizado facilmente por planilhas de Excel/Drive, em banco de dados ou consumido por outros sistemas.

Answer (score 0):

Se a utilização dos dados for para utilização apenas no Python você pode pensar em usar a biblioteca [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) que é padrão nas distribuições do Python.

```
import pickle
l = [1,2,3,4]
with open("test.txt", "wb") as fp:
   pickle.dump(l, fp)

with open("test.txt", "rb") as fp:
  b = pickle.load(fp)
```